# Sharepoint ListItem OnClick event

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to catch the onClick event for a SP.ListItem object in Sharepoint 2010?

I have a list where each item contains a field that is populated with a URL. I would like to open that URL when the item is clicked. The list itself is part of a web-part page, and I would like to open that URL in a different web part on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, all you need is a **DataView Weppart (DVWP)** & a **Content Editor Webpart (CEWP)**.

I created the following scenario successfully and I think it can help you:

1. I have a list with 2 columns : Title & ItemURL , and an empty Webpart Page
2. I added a CEWP to the page, with its content including an IFrame and a javascript function which sets the **src** attribute for the IFrame to a value passed to the function, as shown below :

HTML:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></iframe>
```

javascript:

```
function ChangeIframeSource(itemURL)
{
   $('#myFrame').attr('src', itemURL);
}
```

3. I added a DVWP to the page using SharePoint Designer, and connected the DVWP to my list. You can manipulate XSL of the DVWP easily to do what you want.
4. In the DVWP, where it displays the **Title** value , I changed the xsl by wrapping the (xsl value-of Title) control with an html A tag, and set the href attribute for the A tag to call the function as below :

   ```
       <td class="ms-vb">
           <!--xsl:value-of select="@Title"/--> <!-- comment this line out -->
           <a href="javascript:ChangeIframeSource('{@ItemURL}')"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a>
       </td>
   ```
5. And you're set.. when you click on an item, it should call the javascript function passing the correct url, and the function will change the source of the IFrame to display your content.

I hope this helps